# Android app restarts after device language has changed

Tags: android, restart

I'm working on a Android app that supports several languages. When I put it in background, change device language and then resume the app, it restarts and it seems like the Android system destroys it after changing device language. Do you know if this is what happens? If not, it's certainly regarded to my code, but I don't really know if Android system behaves this way. I've tested on devices with Android 4.3, 4.4, 4.0 versions. On 4.0 it doesn't happen always.

I would like to avoid the app restart, as I don't need to also change the app language along with the device's.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration) + http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges

Comment: Are you using fragments?

Comment: No, not using fragments, only activities.